# Excel Logic Formula?

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with hire dates listed, at 180 days from hire I would like Excel to display in another cell 3 (this 3 is for points), than at 365 days after hire date display 6 instead of 3. (Basically 3 points earn every 6 months from hire date)

Help?

Comment: Use `=ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIF(*hiredate*,NOW(),"m")/6,0)*3`

Comment: Have you searched for anything? What have you tried? This should be a fairly straightforward formula, but we like to see some effort on the asker's behalf.  Let us know where you're stuck, or what formulas aren't working, and we can help guide you.  ...or @ScottCraner can save the day!

Comment: Future questions should include what you have attempted. Similar to @ScottCraner `=ROUNDDOWN((TODAY()-YourDate)/180,0)*3`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date is in cell A1, this will work!

=IF(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"d")<180,0,IF(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"d")<365,3,6))